# How to build fips compliant sqlcipher to call FIPS_mode_set(1)

Tags: java, cryptography, fips, sqlcipher

I built libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with fips compliant as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091905/android-build-openssl-fips-2-0)

I tried to include libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (by creating symbolic link for the file libcrypto.so in android libs folder) and tried to call FIPS_mode_set(1) where I find error - as undefined reference - FIPS_mode_set(1).

Here are steps where in detail I have followed so :

1. In class,net_sqlcipher_database_SQLiteDatabase.cpp (in jni folder) in the sqlcipher code, I included the following headers files :

   ```
   #include <openssl/crypto.h>
   #include <openssl/fips.h>
   #include <openssl/ssl.h>
   ```

   Then I added the following method in the above class

   ```
   /*fips mode enable native native void fips_set_mode(int i) */
   static void fips_set_mode(JNIEnv* env,jobject object,jint i){

   FIPS_mode_set(1); // it should call FIPS_mode_set(1) from fips.c class

   }
   ```

   and I have added above method declaration in the following table

   ```
   //methods
   static JNINativeMethod sMethods[] =
   {
       /* name, signature, funcPtr */
       {"dbopen", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)V", (void *)dbopen},
       {"fips_set_mode","(I)V",(void *)fips_set_mode},
       {"dbclose", "()V", (void *)dbclose},
       {"enableSqlTracing", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", (void *)enableSqlTracing},
       {"enableSqlProfiling", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", (void *)enableSqlProfiling},
       {"native_execSQL", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", (void *)native_execSQL},
       {"lastInsertRow", "()J", (void *)lastInsertRow},
       {"lastChangeCount", "()I", (void *)lastChangeCount},
       {"native_setLocale", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)V", (void *)native_setLocale},
       {"native_getDbLookaside", "()I", (void *)native_getDbLookaside},
       {"releaseMemory", "()I", (void *)native_releaseMemory},
       {"setICURoot", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", (void *)setICURoot},
       {"native_rawExecSQL", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", (void *)native_rawExecSQL},
       {"native_status", "(IZ)I", (void *)native_status},
   };
   ```
2. Then in SQLiteDatabase.java (in the src folder), I have added following native method declaration :

   ```
   //setting
   static public native void fips_set_mode(int i);
   ```
3. Finally, I called above method in loadLibs method of SQLiteDatabase.java

   ```
   //loadlibs

   public static void loadLibs (Context context, File workingDir)
       {
           System.loadLibrary("stlport_shared");
           System.loadLibrary("sqlcipher_android");
           System.loadLibrary("database_sqlcipher");   
           fips_set_mode(1);

   }
   ```
4. Then I did make to compile the sqlcipher code.. But I am getting following error

   ```
   jni/net_sqlcipher_database_SQLiteDatabase.cpp:252: undefined reference to `FIPS_mode_set'.
   ```

Please any suggestion's in this regard would be appreciated

Comment: Did you check if there is another version of OpenSSL in your include path? It probably uses the first one, if that is the one that comes with the system, it is likely to be older.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem ? I'm seeing the same issue in my application?

Comment: It does exist but I have to include in ldlibs of mk file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you verified that the `fips.h` header file exists?  The `Android.mk` file within the root jni folder for android-database-sqlcipher project includes the `external/openssl/include` path during the build.

Comment: It does exist but I have to include in ldlibs of mk file.