# Android build PJSIP with openssl

Tags: android, openssl, pjsip

I'm trying to build PJSIP on Android with SSL/TLS support.

I successfully built OpenSSL following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11170629/1274789) (without fips, as shared-.so libraries) and installed it in ~/android (which created the ~/android/ssl directory).

Now, when i do

```
./configure-android --with-ssl=/home/andrea/android/ssl
```

and look at the config.log, the first error states

```
<ndk-directories-and-stuff>/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: warning: libdl.so, needed by /home/andrea/android/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

a lot of undefined references follow.

As consequence SSL support is disabled:

```
aconfigure:7012: result: ** OpenSSL libraries not found, disabling SSL support **
ac_cv_header_openssl_ssl_h=yes
ac_cv_lib_ssl_SSL_library_init=no
CFLAGS=' -I/home/andrea/android/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include -DPJ_IS_BIG_ENDIAN=0 -DPJ_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -I/home/andrea/android/ssl/include'
LDFLAGS=' -nostdlib -L/home/andrea/android/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib/ -L/home/andrea/android/ssl/lib'
ac_no_ssl=''
libssl_present=''
openssl_h_present='1'
```

but libdl.so exists in the ndk's directory:

```
<ndk-dir>/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib/
```

I guess I have to tell ld where the other libraries are,
what does ld's suggestion mean?

```
try using -rpath or -rpath-link
```

I can't understand what -rpath or rpath-link are or where to apply them .

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I successfully built PJSIP with OpenSSL. please follow the following steps:

First download [openssl-android](https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android) and compile it by reading ReadMe File. (Put your `android-ndk` to `PATH` and execute command `ndk-build` in `openssl-android` root) then just copy `libcrypto.so` and `libssl.so` from `libs/armeabi/` folder to `lib/` folder in root of `openssl-android` (you can create this folder). your directory structure now should be like:
`openssl-android/`
`->apps`
`->crypto`
`->include`
`->jni`
`->lib`
`->libs`
`->...`

now just execute in root directory of pjsip:
`./configure-android --with-ssl=/home/your-user-name/path-to-openssl-android-dir`

for confirmation that openssl is included just pipe this command to grep like:
`./configure-android --with-ssl=/home/your-user-name/path-to-openssl-android-dir | grep -wi ssl`

then you will see this line `result: OpenSSL library found, SSL support enabled`. This means, OpenSSL is now enabled for your PJSIP. Now you can continue normal.

hope this helps.

Comment: hi moonzai, i have followed your step and its working here. but as I need to build pjsip with SSL on lower configured devices like API-9 or  API-11. so please guide me how to do so. really it will help me a lot.

Comment: hi @Johnsmith, its nice to hear that it helped you. From my experience, it should work on these API levels flawlessly. If you are facing error, then tell me that.

Comment: Hi @moonzai, currently I am getting below output on grep command :
Using SSL prefix... /backup/PjsipSetup/openssl-1.0.2s/
checking openssl/ssl.h usability... yes
checking openssl/ssl.h presence... yes
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
** No GnuTLS libraries found, disabling SSL support **
                                                                                                                       
Does that mean SSL compiled successfully ? if yes then what is the path of .so file ? I tried to check on sample app but not getting any .so file related to openssl