# PJSIP_EUNSUPTRANSPORT [status=171060] while createing TCP Config Android PJSIP

Tags: android, tcp, sip, pjsip

I am getting the following error while creating a tcp config for PJSIP in Android.

```
Unable to generate suitable Contact header for registration: Unsupported transport (PJSIP_EUNSUPTRANSPORT) [status=171060]
D/SipTag: Sun Unable to create registration: Unsupported transport (PJSIP_EUNSUPTRANSPORT) [status=171060]
```

Here is my code

```
endpoint?.libInit(epConfig)

// configure transport layer
val transportConfig = TransportConfig()
val pathToCerts = ctx.filesDir.absolutePath

val certPath = "$pathToCerts/cl.pem"
val caPath = "$pathToCerts/ch.pem"
val keyPath = "$pathToCerts/p.key"
transportConfig.tlsConfig.certFile = certPath
transportConfig.tlsConfig.caListFile.plus(caPath)
transportConfig.tlsConfig.privKeyFile = keyPath
transportConfig.tlsConfig.verifyServer = true
endpoint?.transportCreate(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TCP, transportConfig)
endpoint?.libStart()
```

I have searched a lot and tried different things but nothing works. Is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I was missing OpenSSL while compiling PJSIP. You have to compile openssl and add it manually while compiling PJSIP.

Comment: Here is the question on [how to build the pjsip library with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632796/android-build-pjsip-with-openssl)