# Compile OpenSSL FIPS for Android armv6

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl, armv6, fips

I have seen several answers for how to compile OpenSSL for Android, and the FIPS module for Android armv7 (which I followed), but I have yet to figure out how to make the FIPS module for armv6 on Android. Currently if I follow the directions here: [Android, build openssl-fips-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091905/android-build-openssl-fips-2-0) everything works but the app will not run on an armv6 processor.

Answer (score 0):

> but I have yet to figure out how to make the FIPS module for armv6 on Android

You can't when using FIPS Validated OpenSSL provided by Certificate 1747. That FIPS Validated OpenSSL only supports the following two platforms:

- Android on ARMv7 32 bit
- Android on ARMv7 with NEON 32 bit

See the [OpenSSL FIPS 2.0 User Guide](http://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf), Section 3.2, Known Supported Platforms, page 25/198.

I think you need to engage the OpenSSL Foundation for a private label validation that supports the platform and configurations you desire.

---

> if I follow the directions here: Android, build openssl-fips-2.0 everything works

Related: OpenSSL has a tutorial on its Wiki. See [FIPS Library and Android](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/FIPS_Library_and_Android). (Its too large to simply paste in some instructions because of the cross-compile setup).

Modern Android toolchains from the NDK builds for ARMv7 by default. So you might have to revert to an earlier NDK and toolchain that build for ARMv5 by default, and attempt to enable ARMv6.

Unfortunately, I don't know what version of the NDK that might be. I would begin looking between R4 and R6:

- http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r5b-darwin-x86.tar.bz2
- http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r6b-darwin-x86.tar.bz2